# In Alfresco Share, how to sort Workflow I've Started alphabetically?

Tags: sorting, workflow, alfresco

I see that Workflow I've Started page is sorted by due date. I need to sort it by workflow description alphabetically. Is that possible? What files I need to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting is implemented in the `/api/workflow-instances` repository tier (i.e. in `alfresco.war`) web script controller (`org.alfresco.repo.web.script.workflow.WorkflowInstancesGet`), which declares the following:

```
private WorkflowInstanceDueAscComparator workflowComparator = new WorkflowInstanceDueAscComparator();
```

which is then used later on as such:

```
// sort workflows by due date
Collections.sort(workflows, workflowComparator);
```

You need to either override this behavior by providing your controller implementation (which unfortunately doesn't support much of extension or configurability, as you can see), or simply override its `ftl` and re-sort there. You can put your custom FTL in `classpath:alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/workflow/workflow-instances.get.json.ftl`.

Comment: I've successfully sorted my-workflows page by message. But then I see my-workflows page is sorted page by page. For example, if I have 100 workflows it will be split into 2 pages and sorted by due date then in each page it's sorted by message. Is that the right behaviour?

Comment: This is most likely the effect of an FTL customization, where the server side orders workflows still by date and your FTL only re-sort page by page. To handle multiple page I'm afraid you need to override the Java controller for the web script mentioned in my answer.